# IsInRole as Administrator is not validated true

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to redirect login users to admin page if they are administrators as follows,

```
            if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AdminLayout", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
```

But `else`'s return is always performed.

In the database i have inserted a user "admin" with `UserId=1` password "admin"

and in roles table I have `RoleId=1` and `RoleName=Administrator`

and in UsersInRoles table I have `RoleId=1` and `UserId=1`

**Update**

In web.config,

```
   <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
        <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Comment: Check/Post your web.config to make sure everything is configured correctly.

Comment: What do you have defined for your RoleProvider in web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When are you attempting the redirect? If it's before the next page load the `User` object won't yet be resolved. Set a breakpoint in your code and I think you'll discover that `User` is `null`. Of course, `null` will never be in the Administrator role.

To work around this you can

1. Do the redirect on the next page

   OR
2. Grab the username from the login process then find the user logging in and check the role.